# How to list only newly added files between two branches

Tags: git, git-diff

How can I list newly created (added) files between two branches? I can list all files that have been changed with:

```
git diff --color --name-only branch1..branch2
```

But that also contains files, that just changed their content, not necessarily new files. Is there some Git command for this, or do I have to checkout each branch and compare the files, e.g. with bash?

Comment: Note that A..B notation for `git diff` is a convenience feature (for copy'n'paste), as diff operates on endpoints and not on ranges.  `A..B` is just another name for `A B`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just replace `--name-only` with `--name-status`. This way git will show if the file is added, deleted or just modified.

If you are only interested in the new (=added) files you can simply grep for `^A`:

```
git diff --name-status branch1..branch2 | grep ^A
```

Answer (score 73):

You can use **`--diff-filter`** option of [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

```
git diff --color --name-only --diff-filter=A branch1 branch2
```

Comment: This worked for me! Not sure if you need the `--color` in there though.

Comment: The `--color` option was there in OP question, and that's why they are here. @AronAtillaHegedus you are right that all that is needed to list newly added files is `--name-only` (to only list files) and `--diff-filter=A` (to consider only added files).

Answer (score 3):

You would use `...` so that you do not see files that were deleted on one branch to show up as added on the other:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A branch1...branch2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to check for new tracked/added files

```
git diff --color --name-status staging | grep ^A
```