# How to show files present in one branch but not another?

Tags: git

Using git, how can I see what files are in one branch but not another?

Imagine I have:

- BranchA

  - foobar.txt
  - foobaz.txt
- BranchB

  - foobar.txt
  - foofoo.txt

Is there a way to get a list of something like:

- Unique to BranchA

  - foobaz.txt

Or otherwise something similar (the same command could be run backwards to list unique to BranchB files)?

Note I do not care about differences *in* the files but just the presence of the files.

Comment: what about something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000163/git-list-new-files-only

Comment: @marcusshep that _could_ give a good start but I would have to create a temporary branch and export out an entire diff, then apply the diff to see all those staged changes. That seems... hack-like.

Comment: Okay, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222708/git-how-to-list-only-newly-added-files-between-two-branches

Comment: @marcusshep yep, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: no problem, have a good day!