# How to get git diff to list *created* files since last commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am using this to list all *changed* files since last commit:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
```

How do I print only files which have been *added* since last commit (i.e. not deleted or updated)?

If there's no way, then how do I print the *action* next to the name, so I can parse it out and filter on only `added` files?

Comment: I think you want the [`--diff-filter` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203)

Comment: To view the name of the files as well as their status, you can use [`--name-status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-status)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6879501/9287029

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224187/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+added+files