# bash: check if a file was just added in the current head

Tags: linux, bash, git

In a Linux pipeline (Ubuntu 22.04), it need to do something if the file was just added in the current head.

To be more clear, what is the command `git_just_added` that allows this bash

```
for f in $(find -name "abc.txt")
if [[ git_just_added $f]]
then:
   echo $f
```

to print only the files added in the last commit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224187/7976758 `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A @~ @` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+added+files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use this:

```
for f in $(find . -name "abc.txt"); do
  if git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD~ HEAD | grep -q "^$(echo $f | sed 's/^\.\///')$"; then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

For others file name, you can list files that were added in the latest commit `git diff-tree` and `git show`

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=A -r HEAD
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks!
Out of curiosity, what is the `grep` for?